# Turning off the hibernation file in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hibernate

I am a heavy use worker with Lenovo w530 notebook. I carry my bag to and from my office to home. I need more space in C(OS) drive since I have so many softwares installed. I have heard that you can off the hibernation file in windows 8 using `powercfg -h off` in administrator's command prompt. But I turned off that file and ran into a boot problem. I think it might be for the jolting due to rugged journey between my office and home. So in this situation, considering negative sides, will it be a better choice to turn off the hibernation files on my machine?

[image]

Comment: I do this on all my Windows PC's W7~W10 with booting issues.

Comment: What problem notebook can run into due to rugged journey jolting? Is this problem tied to hibernate files anyway?

Comment: I should have said "Without booting issues" in my comment, not sure what your issue is, sorry.

Comment: When Hibernated or truly shut down (either complete or hybrid), the disk is off and it would take *severe* vibration to damage it (probably severe enough to damage the display). In Sleep mode, though, the computer is *slightly* active and disk damage might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

> powercfg **-h** off

You will need to do that as an Administrator. To save time, make a *very* small batch file with that command, and a shortcut to that file. Right-click on the shortcut, select *Properties*, click the *Advanced* button and select *Run as Administrator*.

You can make a similar batch file and shortcut to turn Hibernate on, if desired.

That said, you can probably get **far** more space on your drive by cleaning up unneeded files:

1. Right-click on the C drive in Explorer, select *Properties*, and click *Disk Cleanup*. Include *Clean up System files*.
2. [Clean the WinSxs directory.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) Not all files can be removed, but a few GB can be saved. See also [Laptop Mag](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/clean-winsxs-folder-to-save-space).

Comment: Sorry for typos I used `powercfg -h off`